# Meteor dynamic MongoDB Collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

We have some collections inside MongoDB which are dynamic, they follow a pattern like "XX_YY" but there can be hundreds of collections like theese.

We can get the pattern by querying inside `db.patterns` collection, but I don't know how can we find thoose patterns inside `db.patterns` and then query thoose we want inside MongoDB, an example in MongoDB would be something like this

```
var collections = db.patterns.find();

db.getCollection(collections[0]).find();
```

How can I achieve this in MeteorJS?

Comment: Have you tried anything in Meteor specifically yet? Mongo selectors and object are pretty easy to manipulate, so I don't really see where your blocking issue is.

Comment: I have tried to do `new Mongo.Collection(name);` for each pattern, but I don't know if that can be really dynamic, for example, when a pattern is destroyed or a new one is created, I don't know how it can affect or if it will be reactive, for example accessing to a newly created pattern collection when the app is already running.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `new Mongo.Collection("XX_YY")` to get the collection with that name.

However there might be consequences if you create multiple `Mongo.Collection`s pointing at the same underlying collection. I've never had any reason to do this, so I don't know. However you can use a cache to avoid creating multiple copies:

```js
var collectionCache = {};

function getCollection(name) {
  var cached = collectionCache[name]
  if (!cached) {
    cached = collectionCache[name] = new Mongo.Collection(name);
  }
  return cached;
}
```

I'm assuming the number of collections is bounded, so you don't have to worry about the cache getting arbitrarily large over time.